# implements interface extends ArrayList class

Tags: java

I created an `interface`:

```
public interface Random<E>{
    // methods signatures
}
```

I know it is unusual to do so but I need to make a class extending the `ArrayList` class and implements this `interface`, so I write some code likes this:

```
public class RandomTest<E> implements Random<E> extends ArrayList<E>{
   // a lot of code
   // overriding methods

    public static void main(String[] args){
    RandomTest<Integer> list = new RandomTest<Integer>();
}
```

But it can't compile. Just keep showing -

> "Syntax error on token "extends", , expected."

I am confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are coding in java, the syntax is

```
Class A extends B implements C,D,E.....
```

you have changed the orders of extends implements....

replace

```
public class RandomTest<E> implements Random<E> extends ArrayList<E>{
```

for

```
class RandomTest<E> extends ArrayList<E> implements ....
```